# Search graylog for string with dash and numerals?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, graylog2

I am having an issue finding the proper query syntax to search for the following string in my graylog messages:

Example strings:

```
/path-one/12/status
/path-one/18/status
/path-one/103/status
/path-one/9821/status
```

These are in the `request_url` field.

I've tried the following:

```
request_url:"/path\-one/.+/status" => Returns No results
request_url:/path-one/.+/status => Malformed in the following location and points to "/path-one/"
request_url:/path\-one/.+/status => Malformed in the following location and points to "/path\-one/"
request_url:/path-one/[0-9]+/status => Malformed in the following location and points to "[0-9]"
```

What is the proper syntax to find the strings I want where the middle section can be a positive number?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/lDa96G/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
\/path-one\/[0-9]+\/status
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/lDa96G/1/).